# Trouble Running Emma

Tags: emma

I am currently trying to get coverage of the Android libraries (specifically android.database.sqlite) in the SDK as part of research and testing of the Android system. I am following [this](http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide_single/userguide.html) guide on using Emma in hopes to use Emma as a tool for coverage. However, just following this guide and running the sample programs doesn't seem to work very well. I can run

```
java -cp out Main
```

just fine, but the moment I try to run

```
java emmarun -cp out Main
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: emmarun
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: emmarun
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: emmarun.  Program will exit.
```

Maybe this is just my lack of experience over a problem with Emma, but could anyone explain to me how I'm supposed to do this? By the way, I have the emma.jar file currently saved in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.33.x86_64/jre/lib/ (the guide said to put it in jre/lib/ext/, but that didn't work, so the Support at my work put it in lib/ instead).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong **emma.jar**

There are 2 **emma.jar** in android's build system.

One is for the **host** (*runs on PC*) the other is for the **target** (*runs on Phone*).

Your problem is using the **target** one to execute **emmarun** command.

---

the one build out under /system/framework/emma.jar is for the phone.

the one in the build system /external/emma/lib/emma.jar is for execute the command.